# Plot table with three categorical variables and one numerical variable using geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this table with three categorical variables and one numerical variable:

```
df <- structure(list(Q = c("q_pol", "q_wh", "q_pol", "q_wh"), 
                     median_all = c(0.667362125626559, 0.624735641188929, 0.548153075210995, 0.398574206026083), 
                     median_half = c(-0.350314785114947,1.42461790732669, 0.372537880024059, 0.44085155122463), 
                     median_third = c(-0.93389146143506,0.236025246988988, -1.02912771930043, 0.0361894830862238), 
                     median_quart = c(-0.112157689065904,  0.704777764871505, -0.848709176683769, 1.24452019211073), 
                     Partcpt = c("Not_Answerer", "Not_Answerer", "Answerer", "Answerer")), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I want to visualize how the values in the `median*` columns distribute over the three categorical variables using `geom_smooth`. To get there I've been doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  # cast all `median*`variables longer:
  pivot_longer(-c(Q, Partcpt)) %>%
  # rename:
  rename(slope_range = name) %>%
  # simplify labels:
  mutate(slope_range = str_replace(slope_range, ".*_(.*)$", "\\1")) %>%
  # convert slope_range to numerical variable:
  mutate(slope_range_N = case_when(
    slope_range == "all" ~ 1,
    slope_range == "half" ~ 2,
    slope_range == "third" ~ 3,
    TRUE                    ~ 4)
  ) %>%
  # plot:
ggplot( 
       aes(x = slope_range_N, y = value, color = Q)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```

**Two problems here**: first, the conversion of `slope_range` to numeric seems unprofessional; second, and more importantly, the resulting plot **does not show the distribution of `value` by `Partcpt`**. How can that be included as the fourth variable in the plot?

[image]

**EDIT**:

Maybe the following goes some way toward a solution, the basic idea being that the `Q`values and the `Partcpt` values are cast into a single column (rather than two different ones):

```
# df with `Q`:
df_Q <- df1 %>% 
  select(Q, slope_range,  value, slope_range_N) %>%
  rename(Cat = Q)

# df with `Partcpt`
df_Partcpt <- df1 %>% 
  select(Partcpt, slope_range,  value, slope_range_N) %>%
  rename(Cat = Partcpt)

# bind:
plot_df <- bind_rows(df_Q, df_Partcpt)

# plot:
ggplot(plot_df,
       aes(x = slope_range_N, y = value, color = Cat)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.4, se = FALSE)
```

Just how to have merely **two colors for the two `Q`values and two line types for the two `Partcpt`values**, I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by unprofessional?

Comment: I seem to remember ppl converting char variables to factor but don't remember the details...

Comment: What's the purpose of the `case_when`? Why not just `as.numeric(as.factor(slope_range))` with levels in whatever order? I'm also confused on the purpose of this plot—what are you trying to show exactly, and how do you want to add this 4th variable? Like you'd have an additional set of lines per `Partcpt` value?

Comment: Wonderful solution to the first problem! What I'm expecting from inclusion of the `Partcpt` values is a distinction between **line types**: for example, solid for `Answerer` and dotted for `Not_Answerer` (while the `Q` values are distinguished by `color`)

Comment: So like mapping to `linetype`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There should be four lines in total - two, say, blue and two, say, red for the two levels of `Q`; one red and one blue should be solid, and one red and one blue should be dotted for the two levels of `Partcpt`, and there should be a key explaining the colors and linetypes.

Comment: Please see edited question. The final solution shouldn't be far from there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is partly just an improvement on the data wrangling. It looks like you overthought / overengineered your process. When you reshape the data, get numbers from factor levels from your slope variable, which you can do within `pivot_longer`. Then map to the linetype. One thing to note is you've only got one observation per slope-participant-Q combination, so your LOESS model isn't totally appropriate with so few observations (you'll get a wall of warnings about this). You could instead use a spline if you wanted.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(-Q, -Partcpt), names_to = "slope_range", 
               names_transform = list(slope_range = ~as.numeric(as.factor(.))))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = slope_range, y = value, color = Q, linetype = Partcpt)) +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "black")))
```

[image]

You can pass arguments to `loess` if you need. Generally with something like this, however, I usually prefer doing the modeling myself across a larger span. I think this is similar to what `geom_smooth` does under the hood, but it can be useful to have direct access to it. Here I'll make LOESS models for each Q-participant combo, then use those to predict values for a bunch of points along the domain of `slope_range`. Then use `geom_line` directly. The default line width is different between `geom_smooth` and `geom_line`, but you can adjust that easily.

```r
df_modeled <- df_long %>%
  group_by(Q, Partcpt) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(loess_mod = purrr::map(data, ~loess(value ~ slope_range, data = .)),
         x = purrr::map(data, ~seq(min(.$slope_range), max(.$slope_range), by = 0.1)),
         pred = purrr::map(loess_mod, ~predict(., newdata = unlist(x)))) %>%
  unnest(pred, x)

head(df_modeled)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   Q, Partcpt [1]
#>   Q     Partcpt      data             loess_mod     x   pred
#>   <chr> <chr>        <list>           <list>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1   0.667 
#> 2 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1.1 0.598 
#> 3 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1.2 0.496 
#> 4 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1.3 0.373 
#> 5 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1.4 0.236 
#> 6 q_pol Not_Answerer <tibble [4 × 2]> <loess>     1.5 0.0949

ggplot(df_modeled, aes(x = x, y = pred, color = Q, linetype = Partcpt)) +
  geom_line() +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your good work. There's something wrong though with the factorization: value 1.24452019 (q_wh, Answerer, quart) should be 4 not 3.

Comment: You can rearrange the levels before converting to numeric, either while pivoting, after pivoting, or by changing the column order before pivoting

Answer (score 1):

From before the edit, I can get the four lines in two colours and dashed vs. solid by mapping the linetype by Partcpt. All I did was add `linetype=Partcpt` to the `aes()` call.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  # cast all `median*`variables longer:
  pivot_longer(-c(Q, Partcpt)) %>%
  # rename:
  rename(slope_range = name) %>%
  # simplify labels:
  mutate(slope_range = str_replace(slope_range, ".*_(.*)$", "\\1")) %>%
  # convert slope_range to numerical variable:
  mutate(slope_range_N = case_when(
    slope_range == "all" ~ 1,
    slope_range == "half" ~ 2,
    slope_range == "third" ~ 3,
    TRUE                    ~ 4)
  ) %>%
  # plot:
  ggplot( 
    aes(x = slope_range_N, y = value, color = Q, linetype=Partcpt)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey")) # Line changes colours
```

The plot output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Okay, quite beautiful already. Just one minor adjustment: how can I get a neutral color such as black for the `Partcpt`keys?

Comment: I've now made an edit to show you how to change the color based on Q.

Comment: There's been a misunderstanding: the keys (or guides) need to be changed: color for `Q`, black or grey for `Partcpt`